# .html unique site verifcation with download with PHP

Tags: php, html

Hi i want to make a verification script like the google webmaster tools.

Where you have to download a .html file which has a unique string for each user. then my website calls for that script to ensure the site is verified.

heres how I want it to work, in my database i have a field which stores a unique string for each user.

the user then downloads a file with this string

uploads it to their site and my website calls for it.

What i am thinking is when the user presses the download button

```
$FileName = "veri_".$username.".html";
$fh = fopen($FileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $ustring;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

how would i go about a user downloading this file and then deleting the file of my server. and is that the best way to do it

Comment: You do not need to make a file. The browser receiving your HTTP response doesn't know if you used a file to generate the response or not, it just knows the headers you sent and the body data you sent. Search "php force download" for the right headers to send, then just `echo $stringData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 unlink("veri_".$username.".html");
 header("Location: download.php?file=".$username);
```

however this has to be at very top before any output